# Counting Byte Occurrence in Read Files in BPF

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf

I am relatively new to BPF and trying to write a program that counts the occurrence of each byte read from a file (later will calculate entropy).

The idea is to have two BPF_PERCPU_ARRAYS to circumvent stack size limitations. To one, I will copy the first 4096 bytes of the content of the written file, and with the other, I will count the occurrence of each possible value of a byte.

The described arrays are initialized like this:

```
struct data_t {
    u8 data[4096];
};

struct counter_t {
    u32 data[256];
};

BPF_PERCPU_ARRAY(storage, struct data_t, 1); //to store the buffer
BPF_PERCPU_ARRAY(countarr, struct counter_t, 1); //to count occurrences
```

and used later in a function:

```
//set both arrays to zero
int zero = 0;
struct data_t *pstorage = storage.lookup(&zero);
struct counter_t *pcountarr = countarr.lookup(&zero);


//check if init worked
if (!pstorage)
    return 0;
if (!pcountarr)
    return 0;

//copy data to storage
bpf_probe_read((void*)&pstorage->data, sizeof(pstorage->data), (void*)buf);
    
u8 tmpint = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 4095; i++){
    if (i == count){
        break;
    }
    tmpint = pstorage->data[i];

    //TROUBLE IS HERE
    //bpf_trace_printk("Current Byte: %d", (int)tmpint); //THIS IS LINE A
    //pcountarr->data[tmpint]++; //THIS IS LINE B
}
```

The last two lines that are commented out are the ones giving me trouble. Uncommenting line A gives me the error
*invalid access to map value, value_size=4096 off=4096 size=1
R8 min value is outside of the allowed memory range
processed 102513 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 4 total_states 981 peak_states 977 mark_read 459*

with R8 (are R8 and R8_w the same?) being
*R8_w=map_value(id=0,off=4096,ks=4,vs=4096,imm=0)*

Doing so with Line B results in pretty much the same problem. At this point im decently lost with my experience and wish i had posted this several days ago :D...

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning zero to `i` but it is defined outside of the loop. `for(i = 0; i < 4095; i++){`. I suspect that `i` is not an unsigned number and thus can have a negative minimum value according to the verifier. Would define `i` as a u16 and see if that fixes the issue:
`for(u16 i = 0; i < 4095; i++){`